# Is this event listener behavior as expected in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I bumped into some unexpected behavior when trying to refer to a variable outside of an event handler.

Below is function called `update` that joins data with div elements. In this case, there's only one data point, so only one div element is rendered. The function also takes in a number `currentState` as an argument. The div element has a click event listener, which prints out the `currentState` number and increments a global variable `state` by 1. The original value of `state` is 5. Then the click handler calls `update` with the incremented `state` as a parameter.

When the div is clicked, `currentState` that's passed into `update` increments as expected. This is evident from the output of `console.log("update called. currentState: ", currentState)`.

However, inside of the 'click' event handler, `currentState` remains at 5 regardless of how many times the div element is clicked.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that when the 'click' event listener is created in D3, it holds onto whatever context existed at that time. And because that listener is attached to the div only when it first enters the DOM, that context is never updated.

An easy fix for this issue is just not to attach the click listener on the enter selection, but rather outside of the call to `join`. That way, the listener will be updated each time `update` is called.

I basically have two questions. I wanted to confirm whether I'm correctly understanding what's happening. And second, is this behavior in D3 favorable? Perhaps I'm missing an advantage to it. Although this example's a bit contrived, I would have liked for the click handler to refer to the value of `currentState` that gets updated with each call to `update`. Or is it not good practice to attach listeners on the enter selection?

```
const data = ['randomString']

let state = 5

function update (currentState) {
  console.log("update called. currentState: ", currentState)
  d3.selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    .join(enter => enter.append('div')
      .style('width', '50px')
      .style('height', '50px')
      .style('background', 'red')
      .on('click', function () {
        console.log("click event. currentState: ", currentState)
        state += 1
        update(state)
    }))
}

update(state)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complement to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74495920/5768908), which explains correctly what's happening in D3, this is not a D3 behaviour, this is how JavaScript works.

Here's a demo for showing what's happening with just JavaScript, no D3. Just as in your example when `foo` is created it depends on its context and therefore on the `currentState` value. For a simple comparison with your D3 code, `foo` is stored in an object, so it's not created again every time `update` is called.

Thus, as expected, modifying the `currentState` value has no effect on `foo` after it has been created: it will log `5` every time, not `5`, `6`, `7` etc...

```js
let state = 5;
const obj = {};

function update(currentState) {
  if (!obj.foo) obj.foo = () => console.log(currentState);
  obj.foo();
  state += 1;
};

update(state);
update(state);
update(state);
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that your initial `on` binding is the only one that d3 uses in your case. Let's analyse this code:

```
  d3.selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    // ...
    .join(enter => enter.append('div')
      .on('click', function () {
        console.log("click event. currentState: ", currentState)
        state += 1
        update(state)
    }))
```

What is this doing?

1. Select all `div` that exist in the DOM so far
2. Attach `data` to them
3. If there are less `div` nodes than `data` entries, create a new `div` for each one and attach a click handler which logs `currentState`

What happens if you run this code a second time? At step 3, there is **already a div for each data entry** and thus no new `div` is created and no new click handlers are attached unless if the `data` changes.